# Add a field with dropdown option to civicrm profile

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, civicrm

Hiii
   hiw can i add a field with dropdown option to civicrm profile? i added some civicrm fields with my drupal registration form. There is work addresss and home address, i want an option to select the primary address from this in the registration form. I found the option in civicrm profile page.   How can i add this to my drupal registration form??
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an option in civicrm administration page to customize profile data. Please check administer->Customize->custom data . You can add additional fields from here.